# „Eine Sache durch[zu]ziehen ist nicht immer leicht.“

Tags: infinitive, comma

> Eine Sache durchziehen ist nicht immer leicht.
>   Eine Sache durchzuziehen ist nicht immer leicht.

Sind beide Formen korrekt? Und wie kann ich erklären, dass dort kein Komma hin muss, wenn ich die zweite Variante wähle?

Answer (score 2):

Wenn der erweiterte Infinitiv (das ist einer) das Subjekt des Satzes ist (ist er), kann er sowohl mit als auch ohne *zu* stehen. Also sind beide Varianten richtig.

Beim Infinitiv mit *zu* kann grundsätzlich ein Komma stehen, muss aber nicht (Sofern nichts zwingend das Komma erfordert, was hier nicht der Fall ist). Das darfst du dir aussuchen:

> Eine Sache durchzuziehen ist nicht immer leicht.
>
> Eine Sache durchzuziehen, ist nicht immer leicht.

(Es gibt übrigens, bis auf eine, nur Sonderregeln, die *erlauben*, bei einem Infinitiv mit "zu" Kommas wegzulassen. Es *darf* fast immer eines stehen, außer der Infinitiv ist von einem Modalverb abhängig - Wenn du dir also angewöhnst, immer ein Komma zu setzen, bist du auf der sichereren Seite.)

Comment: Dan würde ich vorschlagen, du ziehst eine Grammatik oder die Regeln des Rechtschreibrats (§75ff) zu Rate - Die Fälle, in denen bei einem Infinitiv kein Komma stehen *muss*, sind zu umfangreich, um sie hier aufzuführen. z.B. http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/PartAdjInf.html